# Using VBA, split string and set first item only to variable?

Tags: string, vba, split

What is the easiest way to set my variable = to the first item of the string after split?
myvar should = "this"

```
  mystring = "this,that,theother"
  myvar = split(mystring, ",")
```

Comment: `Split(mystring, ",")(0)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`myvar = split(mystring, ",")(0)` will work since `split(mystring, ",")` is a 0-based array.